# Add information to a Json file in Python using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Json and Python and have been trying to update a Json file, I'm struggling with the process to read, update and save the file with the old and new information. I try it using only Json Strings but had a lot of problems with the format and I prefer to read the Json to a Pandas Dataframe, update and then save it. I am able to save and update the dataframe, but have problems reading the file to the Dataframe.

Everything is working fine except the read_json function:
    `df = df.read_json("registryDB.json")`

I am getting this error:
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_json'`

This is the function code:

```
df = df.read_json("registryDB.json")

 df = df.append({
'Name': 'John', 
'User': 'John123', 
'Last Name': 'Doe', 
'Age': 27, 
'Gender': 'm', 
'Location': 'US', 
'Date': timestamp
}, ignore_index=True)

file = df.to_json(orient='table')

with open("registryDB.json", "w") as dataFile:
   json.dump(file, dataFile)
```

I don't know if this is the best or correct way of doing this, so if you know any other, any advise would be awesome.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to posting on SO. :) Please always aim to include all the imports that you are using to make your code snippet minimal functional. Seems like you're already using Python's `json` module for writing back to the file. I'd suggest to use it also for editing the data and skip using `pandas` entirely. See my answer below for more info and also for a quick note on where your error comes from.

Answer (score 1):

## Solving the `AttributeError`

The [`.read_json` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) is a function in `pandas` and not a method on a `pandas.DataFrame` object. Therefore you'll need to call it like so:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_json("registryDB.json")
```

You are *creating* the `df` by calling the `pandas` `read_json()` function.

## Easier way to work with JSON

In Python, there's an easier way to interact with JSON: the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) that is part of Python's standard library.

You can quickly read in a JSON file to a Python dictionary. Then you can work with it just like any Python dictionary. When you're ready to save it back to a JSON file, it's another straightforward call:

```py
import json


with open("registryDB.json", "r") as fin:
    data = json.load(fin)

# do your edits on the data dict

with open("new_file.json", "w") as fout:
    json.dump(data, fout)
```

Comment: Thank you! I already try the `df = pd.read_json("registryDB.json")` line and still have issues. I also try:

`dict[ticket] = [
    user, 
    appName, 
    path, 
    hostname, 
    state, 
    timestamp]

with open("registryDB.json", "r") as fin:
    data = json.load(fin)
    
    dict.update(data)
    
with open("registryDB.json", "w") as fout:
    json.dump(dict, fout)`

Do you know how to fix the ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required?

Thank you so much for the help!